# Resetear valor de etiqueta <p> al volver atrás

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

quisiera hacer que el valor modificado a través de JS de una etiqueta p volviera a ser el predeterminado sin tener que hacer F5. El valor de p (.costetotal) varía según x elementos selccionados, cuando hago submit y vuelvo atrás ese valor deberia ser 15 y no el que obtuvo por última vez, aqui os dejo el codigo en cuestión

```
<div class="row div_preciototal">
                    <p class="offset-1 col-md-10 texto_preciototal  grid-10" id="costetotal" >
                        Total: 15€ </p>
                    @if(session()->has('validado'))

                        <input type="submit" id="realizar" class="button_pedido green offset-1 col-md-10" disabled="false"
                               value="Realizar pedido y pagar"/>
                    @else
                        <div class="col-md-10 offset-1">
                        <p>Necesitas loguear para realizar el pedido o solicitar presupuesto</p>
                        <a href="{{route('login')}}" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Login</a>
                        </div>
                    @endif
</div>
```

Y el JS:

```
 <script>

        function actualiza() {
            var total = 0;
            var precios = document.querySelectorAll('.micheckbox');

            precios.forEach(function (precio) {
                total += precio.checked ? parseFloat(precio.value) : 0;

            });

            document.getElementById('costetotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + total + '€';
            var ptotal = document.getElementById("ptotal");
            ptotal.value = total;
</script>
```

Comment: Si colocas `document.getElementById('costetotal').innerHTML = "Total: " + 15 + '€';`
después del submit no da?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí regresas y te toma el valor enviado..

has intentado borrar el cache al cambiar de vista? Puedes crear un middleware para controlar la carga al dar clic atrás, en teoría, debería de servirte.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){


header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');


header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');


header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);


header('Pragma: no-cache');


return $next($request);
```

}